Проблема с отладчиком Python в VS Code
При попытке запустить скрипт на Python в VS Code (Run > Run Without Debugging) вместо самого запуска получаю поле Select Debugger, где нужно выбрать Python Debugger. В конечном итоге получаю сообщение "Connection is disposed." Причем до определенного момента все как-то через раз запускалось.
Пробовал переустановить VS Code и его расширения (Python и Python Debugger), не помогло...
Файлы Python через консоль прекрасно запускаются, но в VS Code ничего не работает.
UPD: Помогло полное удаление VS Code и, что самое главное, файлов конфигурации, %APPDATA%\Code\ и %USERPROFILE%\.vscode с последующей переустановкой...но помогло не полностью. Все равно при Run > Run Without Debugging выводится Python Debugger, нажимаю на него и скрипт все таки запусткается. Run Python File тоже не работает, пока не ты скрипт через Run > Run Without Debugging не запустишь...
